# Проверка домена email?

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой есть вариант проверки или готовый виджет для введенного email в input(Например,чтобы пропускал gmail.com, а несуществующие не пропускал)?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp, но в любом случае, есть только один надежный способ проверить почту - отправить письмо  и дождатся ответа.

Comment: Надо проверить почту или только существование почтового домена? во втором случае достаточно проверить наличие MX-записи в зоне... типа `$result = dns_get_record($hostname, DNS_MX)`

Comment: Заодно посмотрите комментарии - к dns_get_record() и к getmxrr().